# Firebase Auth REST API - signing in with email/password doesn't return refresh token

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When I post a sign-in request to `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=<API_KEY>`, the response body is missing the refresh token and expiration time even though the sign-in operation itself succeeds. It looks like this:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
  "localId": <LOCAL_ID>,
  "email": <EMAIL>,
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": <ID_TOKEN>,
  "registered": true
}
```

It *does* return an id token, but I've tried using that to authenticate RTDB requests (in the form of `<DATABASE_URL>/.../node.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>`) and they fail with HTTP error 401 even though my database has public read/write rules.

The response body returned by a sign-up request (`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=<API_KEY>`) doesn't have the same problem.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `returnSecureToken` set to true in the request as documented in the [REST API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).